# get no of matches

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have a table contains 6 int column and contain more than 10000 rows i have 6 values i want how many columns value matches to that number and group according liy

my table is as below

```
-----------------------------------------
id | col1 | col2 | col3 |col4 |col5|col6
-----------------------------------------
1  |  2   |   3  |   7  |  2  |  7 | 9
2  |  5   |   8  |   4  |  3  |  6 | 4
3  |  7   |   3  |   5  |  6  |  5 | 8
```

matching seq `7 3 5 6 5 9`

out put should b like this

```
6 / 6
0
5/6
3  |  7   |   3  |   5  |  6  |  5 | 8
4/6
0
3/6
0
2/6
1  |  2   |   3  |   7  |  2  |  7 | 9
1/6
0
```

Comment: is it homework?

Comment: Can you share an additional output example? I think I understand why the '5/6' result is correct but the '2/6' doesn't match any rules I can think of.

Comment: @FredShope it matches 2 columns (col2 (3) and col6 (9))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) operator. You can write an expression that checks each column for the right value. Something like the following is a good starting point:

```
SELECT 
  ID
, COL1
, COL2
, COL3
, COL4
, COL5
, COL6
, CASE WHEN COL1 = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN COL2 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN COL3 = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN COL4 = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN COL5 = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN COL6 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NUM_OF_MATCHES
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

From that query, you should be able to GROUP BY or ORDER BY the results however you want.

Comment: @ joe Obbish thanks for your answer one more thing .If i want to calculate estimation matches will 7 3 5 6 5 ? the sixth number will be any number and i want to the matches